# Cannot read property '_id' of undefined

Tags: javascript, mongodb, weather-api

I'm trying to insert documents from this [weather API](https://www.npmjs.com/package/weather-js) into my MongoDB. I keep getting `Cannot read property '_id' of undefined` with these error

```
undefined
/Users/Ekom/WebstormProjects/WebApps/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:236
          throw err
          ^

TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined
    at Collection.insertMany (/Users/Ekom/WebstormProjects/WebApps/node_modules/mongodb/lib/collection.js:513:17)
    at Collection.insert (/Users/Ekom/WebstormProjects/WebApps/node_modules/mongodb/lib/collection.js:825:15)
    at /Users/Ekom/WebstormProjects/WebApps/app.js:26:24
    at connectCallback (/Users/Ekom/WebstormProjects/WebApps/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:314:5)
    at /Users/Ekom/WebstormProjects/WebApps/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:233:11
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
```

**app.js**

```
mongodb.MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/weatherdb', function(error, database) {
    if(error != null) {
        throw error;
    }

    collection = database.collection('data');

        weather.find({search: 'Ottawa, ON', degreeType: 'C'}, function(err, documents) {
        if(err) console.log(err);

     //   console.log(JSON.stringify(documents, null, 2));
    });

console.log(documents);

            collection.insert(documents, { w:1

                },
                function (error, result) {
                    if (error != null) {
                        console.log("ERROR: " + error);
                    }
                });



});
```

Please can someone who knows what I am doing wrong kindly point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var mongodb=require("mongodb");
var weather = require('weather-js');

mongodb.MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost/weatherdb', function(error, database) {
    if(error != null) {
        throw error;
    };

    weather.find({search: 'Ottawa, ON', degreeType: 'C'}, function(err, documents) {
        if(err) console.log(err);
        console.log(documents);
        database.collection('data').insert(documents,function (error, result) {
            if (error) {
                console.log("ERROR: " + error);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Your `console.log` line was outside the callback function therefore unaware of "documents" and your insert statement was a bit off too, the code above worked for me.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Do you have an idea of how I can add multiple locations?

Comment: I got [these](https://jsbin.com/titoso/edit?js,output) functions that pull for different cities but I'm not of how I can add them to MongoDB